# Words Starting with Double Consonants

Tags: loanwords, phonology, phonetics

Double consonants often appear in the middle or at the end of a word like:

> ki**tt**y, Ei**ff**el, thri**ll**er, bri**ll**iant
>
> ba**ss**, gue**ss**, basketba**ll**

However, I wonder if there are any words (including loanwords) which begin with the double consonants. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Llama :) Are Welsh place names allowed as part of the answer? ;)

Comment: There are surnames, like Ffolkes.

Comment: And the first name Ffion...

Comment: or Lloyds, I know. I think the question is very general, so, the place names are also welcome, since not notional nouns are more desirable.

Comment: Llywelyn, Llewelyn

Comment: Mmbatho ... a city in South Africa, near the border with Botswana

Comment: There are records of  families with the surname  *FFISKE* in East Anglia.

Comment: "Zzz" is in the dictionary, and "llano - n.  An extensive plain with or without vegetation"

Comment: Mmm*pie* has three.

Comment: Initial double letters are found in English either on words borrowed from other spelling systems where the double letters are standard, or proper names, or (frequently) both. No native uncontracted English word is spelled regularly with geminate letters.

Comment: @JohnLawler What is it about proper names which looks like having English origin? Like Lloyd?

Comment: Lloyd comes from Welsh.

Comment: English has been borrowing for a **long** time.

Comment: *Rrrrroll up the Rrrrim to Win* has two examples. .. ;)

Comment: Aah. Experimental spellings, like ultralite aircraft, are exempt from many regulations, and extremely useful, in ultraspecial contexts.

Comment: If we are allowing Welsh place names then, *Llanfairpwllgwyngyllgogerychwyrndrobwllllantysiliogogogoch* ought not to be forgotten. It is the longest place name in the British Isles - a village on the Isle of Anglesey. In English it means: *St Mary's church in the hollow of the white hazel near to the fierce whirlpool and the church of St Tysilio of the red cave*

Comment: It's only the longest in spelling, which doesn't count. And it wouldn't be if Welsh left spaces between words in compounds, like English does and German doesn't, either.

Comment: What is the rationale for asking for loan words and "native" words, assuming they can be distinguished?

Comment: @JohnLawler But it would still be the same length (or even longer?) if they left spaces. Are you suggesting that village names like *Milton-under-Wychwood*, *Bourton-on-the-Water*, and *Moreton-in-the-Marsh* do not count as 'long names'? They are all in England and are of as many letters in some cases (19) as places included in a list of long names, such as *Newtownmountkennedy* in the Republic of Ireland.

Comment: And Winchester-on-the-Severn has 23 letters. My point is that even allowing for extended names we cannot get anywhere near *Llanfairpwllgwyn...*. with 78 letters. Though there is one in New Zealand with a Maori name, of 98 letters.

Comment: Nothing in spelling counts for "English". Only "English spelling", which is a completely different phenomenon.

Comment: Should exclude non-native words, else plenty of answers would be possible.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns trivia. And lacks signs of research.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because should be asked on puzzling.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loanword *[llano](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/llano?s=t)* from Spanish.

> n. an extensive grassy plain with few trees.

Comment: But isn't the Spanish 'll' a vowel?  It's pronounced rather like the English 'y'.

Comment: It's a matter of dialect. In many parts of central and south America and in the canary islands it's pronounced like a j.

Comment: @jamesqf the pronunciation of words like *llave* and *llamo* use the sound /ʝ/ or /ʎ/ which are not vowel sounds. It is similar to the English /j/ as in *university*, a word which is not preceded by *an*.

Comment: Yes, "ll" in Spanish is regarded as it's own letter, pronounced roughly like "y" in "yes".  But since it's two letters in English that means that "llano" and "llama" and a bunch of other loanwords from Spanish begin with two "l" characters.